# symfony 1.0 won't return a proper instance on local machine

Tags: symfony1

I recently had to start making small changes to an existing site so I downloaded it and tried to run it but get an error:

```
Call to undefined method sfContext::getController() in 
/home/user/www/site.com/web/index.php on line 16
```

I tried to figure out which file is being loaded by inserting these lines with this command in index.php right before the dispatch call.

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass('sfContext');
$classFile = $reflection->getFileName();
die($classFile);

sfContext::getInstance()->getController()->dispatch();
```

And it looks like file loaded is:

```
/home/user/www/site.com/lib/vendor/symfony1.0/test/unit/sfContextMock.class.php
```

This symfony1.0 site works fine on original server but not on my local machine.
I checked php version and php.ini and they are identical. I cant figure out why wrong class is being loaded or what the problem is.

**Here is the index.php file**

```
<?php

define('SF_ROOT_DIR',    realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/..'));
define('SF_APP',         'front');
define('SF_ENVIRONMENT', 'prod');
define('SF_DEBUG',       true);


require_once(SF_ROOT_DIR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'apps'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.SF_APP.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');

sfContext::getInstance()->getController()->dispatch();
```

Comment: Does PHP version are the same on both machine (prod & local)? It seems that your 1.0 version has been modify. It doesn't use `ReflectionClass` by default but [a basic `require_once`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.0/data/skeleton/controller/controller.php). Can you add the whole `index.php` file in your question?

Comment: @j0k PHP versions are identical: 5.3.3 I added that reflection class stuff myself to see where the sfContext class is pulled from, so the 3 lines you see are the ones i added just to troubleshoot. The original index file is the same as it was before with the require and dispatch call.

Comment: Ok, but can we see the `index.php` file anyway? By default, there isn't 16 lines in this file. Have you tried to access the dev env (something like `frontend_dev.php`) ?

Comment: @j0k I added the index.php to the description, you can look at it. frontend_dev.php generates the same error.

Comment: Which version of symfony 1.0? Does it use propel or doctrine?

Comment: @j0k version 1.0.20-PRE using Doctrine

Comment: You should try to update to the lastest one available ([1.0.22](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.0/CHANGELOG))

Comment: Maybe there is some stuff inside an `autoloader.yml` file making the `test` directory more important than `lib`? Do you have the `lib/vendor/symfony/lib/util/sfContext.class.php` file?

Comment: @j0k After upgrading to latest symfony 1 (1.0.22) the problem fixed itself. Please add this suggestion as an answer and I'll mark it as solved by you. Thank you.

Comment: Answer posted (in fact undeleted & updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update to the lastest one available ([1.0.22](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.0/CHANGELOG)).